# How to make react redux state information unavailable on dev tools?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am working on a react application, with the react-redux state. Everything works fine with the redux state, but the only issue is that the redux state is stored in local storage and I want to disable it for other people to view it.

Since it is in development it is fine, but when it is in production, it will become an issue to show sensitive information to general users.

Is there a way to disable the redux state information on the dev tools for others or some other way to solve this issue?

Do check the screen shot attached

[image: Dev console screenshot]

Comment: JavaScript runs in the browser so all information used by JavaScript can be read by the browser and the dev tools. To hide sensitive information you have to store it on the server

Comment: Could you please guide me the way, is it a small or do I have to change the whole redux store usage?

Comment: It depends on what you want to hide and why. Hiding a 3rd party api key can be done by proxying your request through your server (also solves CORS errors). Sometimes you don't need to hide the key because the key will only work from your domain so stealing the key to use on another site will not work.

Comment: As observed from the screenshot, Redux store has all the necessary data required for the app to run, sensitive information like all users data. And I cannot show such data to general users. So basically I want to hide the redux store data from others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot hide local storage data from the user, whether that comes from Redux or otherwise. You could possibly obfuscate it, but as the client code contains the means to deobfuscate it would be fairly simple to reverse. Also, the data will still be presumably sent over the nerwork, which is easy to intercept.

If your design requires data to be persisted on the client that cannot be exposed to the user and cannot be expired, I would suggest you rethink your design. Note that even with obfuscation any kind of XSS attack will possibly have an opportunity to snoop on heap values.

Comment: So is there any other better way you might suggest to me ? It is for my internship, I am already hitting my deadline,  I have spent day and night for 50 days and at the end in production I am facing this issue, so please guide me.

Comment: @RitteshP.V Firstly - sorry to hear you're in dire straits. Firstly, I'd want to check if the data really was as sensitive as I feared. Then, I'd see if I could remove the really sensitive parts without affecting the app. If that didn't work, I'd try and move the work and memory to server side. You could use sessions to look up the relevant data for a user per request. Hope that helps.

Comment: I am using react as front end and node js as my backend. I am not doing any session-based queries, for example I have to show the tournaments for users who aren't logged as well In that case I have to store it somewhere. the second example is that I need to show all the registrations that the user has done. So I need to store this information somewhere , so if not redux store where can I store it securely